# primefaces 6.1 select one menu is populated but refuses to show values

Tags: filter, primefaces, selectonemenu

I am trying to filter using a Select One Menu using PrimeFaces 6.1. But the menu does not drop down to show its values. It acts as if it is disabled. I have wrapped my datable with `<h:form>` and checked to see if the menu is populated in the browser inspect window.

[image]

Edit:

[image]

Here is the table:

```
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable var="left" value="#{dataFilterView.leftGrid}"
                widgetVar="leftTable"
                filteredValue="#{dataFilterView.filteredLeftGrid}">
                <ui:debug />
                <p:column headerText="Project">
                    <h:outputText value="#{left.projectName}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Company">
                    <h:outputText value="#{left.companyName}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Location" filterBy="left.projectLocation">
                    <h:outputText value="#{left.projectLocation}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Request Name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{left.requestName}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Request Type" filterBy="#{left.requestType}"
                    filterMatchMode="exact">
                    <f:facet name="filter">
                        <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('leftTable').filter()"
                            style="width:70%; box-sizing: border-box;">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}"
                                noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems
                                value="#{dataFilterView.uniqueRequestTypes.entrySet()}"
                                var="data" itemValue="#{data.key}" itemLabel="#{data.value}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{left.requestType}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
```

The ManagedBean is:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dataFilterView")
@SessionScoped
public class DataFilterView {

private String reqType;

private List<LeftGridBean> leftGrid;
private List<LeftGridBean> filteredLeftGrid;

private List<String> uniqueLocations;
private Map<String, String> uniqueRequestTypes;

@ManagedProperty("#{supplierRequestsService}")
private SupplierRequestsService service;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    leftGrid = service.populateLeftGrid();
}

public void setService(SupplierRequestsService service) {
    this.service = service;
}

public List<LeftGridBean> getLeftGrid() {
    return leftGrid;
}

public List<LeftGridBean> getFilteredLeftGrid() {
    return filteredLeftGrid;
}

public void setFilteredLeftGrid(List<LeftGridBean> filteredLeftGrid) {
    this.filteredLeftGrid = filteredLeftGrid;
}

public String getReqType() {
    return reqType;
}

public void setReqType(String reqType) {
    this.reqType = reqType;
}

public List<String> getUniqueLocations() {
    Set<String> locations = new HashSet<>();
    for (LeftGridBean lg : getLeftGrid()) {
        locations.add(lg.getProjectLocation());
    }
    uniqueLocations = new ArrayList<String>(locations);
    return uniqueLocations;
}

public Map<String, String> getUniqueRequestTypes() {
    Map<String, String> requestTypes = new HashMap<>();
    for (LeftGridBean lg : getLeftGrid()) {
        requestTypes.put(lg.getRequestType(), lg.getRequestType());
    }
    uniqueRequestTypes = requestTypes;
    return uniqueRequestTypes;
}
}
```

Domain:

```
public class LeftGridBean {
private String projectName;
private String projectLocation;
private String requestType;
private String requestName;
private String companyName;

public String getProjectLocation() {
    return projectLocation;
}

public void setProjectLocation(String projectLocation) {
    this.projectLocation = projectLocation;
}

public String getRequestType() {
    return requestType;
}

public void setRequestType(String requestType) {
    this.requestType = requestType;
}

public String getRequestName() {
    return requestName;
}

public void setRequestName(String requestName) {
    this.requestName = requestName;
}

public String getProjectName() {
    return projectName;
}

public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}
}
```

and finally the service:

```
@ManagedBean(name="supplierRequestsService")
@SessionScoped
public class SupplierRequestsService {

@ManagedProperty("#{userManager}")
private UserManager usr;

public List<LeftGridBean> populateLeftGrid() {
    List<LeftGridBean> lgbList = usr.getSupplierLeftGridData();
    return lgbList;
}

public List<RightGridBean> populateRightGrid() {
    List<RightGridBean> rgbList = usr.getSupplierRightGridData();
    return rgbList;
}

public void setUsr(UserManager usr) {
    this.usr = usr;
}
}
```

Comment: any javascript errors?

Comment: none whatsoever.

Comment: Looking at how the select actually looks, I suspect custom CSS that is not in the code above is being applied. Try removing all custom css from your code

Comment: Edit: image looks like this after removing all CSS above the data table in the page. Still seems disabled.

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje I have tried opening the xhtml by itself and the select works fine. But if I login and I am redirected to the above page, the datatable gets messed up. I can't how you the code due to restrictions.

Comment: Then check for network 404's

Comment: This is on my localhost.

Comment: You can always get  http 404's even on localhost

Comment: no 404's or JS errors @Kukeltje

Comment: Then I have no clue and unless there is an [mcve] it is impossible to help further

Comment: no value attribute inside selectonemenu?